# Error: ERROR! Copying template src/main/java/package/domain/Entity.java.ejs failed

Tags: jhipster

I have created a **hotelContactInfo.json** file, and I am trying to generate the code with JHipster:

```
{
    "fluentMethods": true,
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipName": "hotel",
            "otherEntityName": "hotel",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "id",
            "ownerSide": true,
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "hotelContactInfo"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "ownerName",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "emails",
            "fieldType": "String[]",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "mobiles",
            "fieldType": "String[]",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "deskInfo",
            "fieldType": "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "address",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "website",
            "fieldType": "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "createdBy",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "createdDate",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "modifiedBy",
            "fieldType": "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "modifiedDate",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20180822085850",
    "dto": "no",
    "service": "serviceImpl",
    "entityTableName": "hotel_contact_info",
    "pagination": "infinite-scroll",
    "microserviceName": "hcm",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "enableEntityAudit": false
}
```

While generating the code, JHipster entity **HotelContactInfo**:

```
Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
Executing jhipster:entity HotelContactInfo
Options: 

Found the .jhipster/HotelContactInfo.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


The entity HotelContactInfo is being updated.

? Do you want to update the entity? This will replace the existing files for this entity, all your custom code will be overwritten Yes, re generate the entity
WARNING! jpaMetamodelFiltering is missing in .jhipster/HotelContactInfo.json, using 'no' as fallback
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

`ERROR! 

Copying template src/main/java/package/domain/Entity.java.ejs failed. [TypeError: /Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity-`: 
server/templates/src/main/java/package/domain/Entity.java.ejs:24

    22| let importJsonIgnoreProperties = false;
    23| let importSet = false;
 >> 24| const uniqueEnums = {}; %><%- include imports -%>
    25| 
    26| <%_ if (databaseType === 'cassandra') { _%>
    27| import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity-server/templates/src/main/java/package/domain/imports.ejs:20
    18| -%>
    19| <%#    Checks which imports are needed -%>
 >> 20| <%
    21| 
    22| for (idx in relationships) {
    23|     if (typeof relationships[idx].javadoc != 'undefined') {

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]
    at Environment.error (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
    at module.exports.error (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1978:18)
    at ejs.renderFile (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/utils.js:197:23)
    at tryHandleCache 

(/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:14)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:482:10)
    at Object.renderContent (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/utils.js:193:9)
    at module.exports.template (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-private.js:636:23)
    at blockTemplate.templates.forEach (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2326:42)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.writeFilesToDisk (/Users/ramanujkumar/rt/rtservices/hcm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2291:45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you have created or edited the `hotelContactInfo.json` file **manually**?

You're supposed to create/update entities by either importing a JDL file or answering questions of the entity generator because this is how the syntax is checked. By editing the json file directly, you by-pass this phase at your own risk.

Here, I suspect that `"fieldType": "String[]"` is invalid because it's not a [type supported by JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#annexes).